# Python Selenium cannot connect to Webdriver Firefox extension

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm using Python 2.7, Selenium 2.35, and Firefox 22.0. When I do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

d = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The Firefox browser opens and stays open. The error below is thrown in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 61, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 114, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 165, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 136, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: u''
```

I then launched Fiddler and tried to initialize the webdriver.Firefox object again:

```
d = wedriver.Firefox()
```

Same error as above. Fiddler shows the following output:

```
{"name":"newSession","status":13,"value":{"message":"b is undefined","stackTrace":[{"methodName":"wdSessionStoreService.prototype.extractCapabilitySetting_",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/session_store.js",
"lineNumber":7951},{"methodName":"wdSessionStoreService.prototype.createSession",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/session_store.js",
"lineNumber":7944},{"methodName":"nsCommandProcessor.prototype.newSession",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js",
"lineNumber":10982},{"methodName":"nsCommandProcessor.prototype.execute",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js",
"lineNumber":10875},{"methodName":"Dispatcher.executeAs/<",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js",
"lineNumber":7750},{"methodName":"Resource.prototype.handle",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js",
"lineNumber":7896},{"methodName":"Dispatcher.prototype.dispatch",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js","lineNumber":7843},{"methodName":"WebDriverServer/<.handle","fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js","lineNumber":10710},{"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js","lineNumber":1935},{"methodName":"ServerHandler.prototype.handleResponse","fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js","lineNumber":2261},{"methodName":"Connection.prototype.process","fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js","lineNumber":1168},{"methodName":"RequestReader.prototype._handleResponse","fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js","lineNumber":1616},{"methodName":"RequestReader.prototype._processBody","fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js","lineNumber":1464},{"methodName":"RequestReader.prototype.onInputStreamReady",
"fileName":"file:///c:/users/username/appdata/local/temp/tmpzqvpr1/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/httpd.js","lineNumber":1333}]}}
```

If i load `localhost:57554` I get:

```
httpd.js

If you're seeing this page, httpd.js is up and serving requests! Now set a base path and serve some files!
```

So the Webdriver appears to be functional, but for some reason Python cannot initiate a session.
Anyone has had this problem before? what could cause this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is caused by the HTTP_PROXY environment variable. Changing the Windows settings via Control Panel does not change the value of the environment variable. Removing the variable from the Python environment before instantiating webdriver solves the problem:

```
import os

if 'HTTP_PROXY' in os.environ:
    os.environ.pop('HTTP_PROXY')
```